# C# visual studio 2015 extension for inserting code in texteditor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, visual-studio-2015, add-in

I need to make extension in VS 2015 and find a way to insert code in texteditor. For example, I made add-in, and when I pull over button, it's automatically added in  xmltext editor () and/or in designer code (private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSnimi;).

I made add-in with alerts, and I want to insert alerts from add-in in place in code that I selected, just like buttons.

Is it possible? And some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to insert text to the current text editor:

```
EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
ts.Text = "private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSnimi;";
```